# Only retain numeric values of 2D list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list:

```
list = {V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, \
z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, \
V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, \
z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, \
V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, \
z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, \
V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, V, z, {0.0771386,
  1.02063*10^-7}, {0.114181, 1.02467*10^-7}}
```

I would like to only retain the numeric values:

```
{{0.0771386, 1.02063*10^-7}, {0.114181, 1.02467*10^-7}}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
   Cases[list, {__?NumericQ}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This worked !

Answer (score 4):

Or

```
DeleteCases[list, _?AtomQ]
```

or

```
Select[list, MatchQ[#, _List] &]
```

.

```
(*   {{0.0771386, 1.02063*10^-7}, {0.114181, 1.02467*10^-7}}   *)
```

Comment: Nice, also works !

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {V, z, V, z, V, z, {0.7, 1.2}, {0.1, 1.5}};
```

Grabbing the @eldo's list and using `SequenceCases`:

```
SequenceCases[list, {s : {Except[_Symbol] ..}} :> s]

(*{{0.7, 1.2}, {0.1, 1.5}}*)
```

Or using `Select`:

```
Select[list, #[[0]] =!= Symbol &]

(*{{0.7, 1.2}, {0.1, 1.5}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {V, z, V, z, V, z, {0.7, 1.2}, {0.1, 1.5}};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
First @ SequenceSplit[list, {_Symbol}]
```

{{0.7, 1.2}, {0.1, 1.5}}

Using `SequenceReplace` (also new in 11.3)

```
SequenceReplace[list, {_Symbol} -> Nothing]
```

{{0.7, 1.2}, {0.1, 1.5}}